# A flutter programming issue

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, flutter-dependencies

Trying to run a translator program code which gives me an error with this line:

```
Translate _translate = new Translate();
```

No idea what is wrong with it.  I imported this library for this code:

```
import 'package:translate/translate.dart';
```

and as the depencencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  google_maps_controller: ^1.2.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  speech_to_text: ^6.1.1
  flutter_tts: ^3.6.3
  flutter_translate: ^4.0.3
  translate: ^1.0.0
  translator: ^0.1.7

translate: ^1.0.0
```

will be thank ful if someone could help me with the issue.

I tried to run the code but it gives me these errors:
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

```
- package:translate

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
lib/main.dart:44:3: Error: Type 'Translate' not found.
  Translate _translate = new Translate();
  ^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:44:3: Error: 'Translate' isn't a type.
  Translate _translate = new Translate();
  ^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:44:30: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'Translate'.
  Translate _translate = new Translate();
                             ^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:484:9)
#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:153:33)
#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:705:47)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:612:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1210:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: Have you run `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: That package is outdated. They only had one release, 3 years ago, before null-safety. Also it doesn't have a `Translate` class. What made you think you could call it like that?

Comment: Thank you! I am a beginner. and I am learning. This is the reason why I made this mistake.

Comment: Yes I tried it and got this: Running "flutter pub get" in speech-to-text...                   2,429ms
Process finished with exit code 0